# VT-x Not Supported, HAXM cannot be installed

Tags: x86, virtualization, windows-10, haxm

I am trying to install HAXM (recommened by android studio) on my windows10 OS, intel virtual tech is enabled and Hyper-v is unchecked but still, I am unable to resolve this issue that "VT-x is not supported, HAXM cannot be istalled".

Comment: HAXM is not Windows 10 compatible. Wait for an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of hardware do you have?  It needs to be "SLAT" compatible.

The emulator’s Hyper-V requirement requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation ( SLAT ) enabled hardware.  SLAT support was introduced to Hyper-V circa Windows Server 2008 as a  mechanism to reduce overhead during address mapping for virtual machines.  Since Hyper-V R2 on Windows 8 requires SLAT hardware, so does the WP8 SDK Emulator.

There are two methods to check if you have SLAT hardware.  The best route is download the SLATStatusCheck tool from CodePlex ( http://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/ ).  This tool runs is a WPF 4.5 app which very simply indicates if you  have SLAT compatible hardware or not.  The tool is open source if you want to see how to do the checks yourself in code.

The other route is CoreInfo.exe, a tool available from SysInternals ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx ).  When you run CoreInfo.exe with a “-v” parameter, you will have a “*” next to  the “EPT Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)” entry.  Note coreinfo must be run in an admin level command prompt.

CoreInfo can sometimes lie!  If you’ve already got Hyper-V running, it may erroneously return a “false negative” on the slat capabilities.  CoreInfo even tells you this in a screen entry (which I overlooked) – “Note: CoreInfo must be executed on a system without a hypervisor running for accurate results”.  Note that SLATStatusCheck returns the correct results regardless of whether Hyper-V is running or not.   The screen show below shows a false SLAT result off my Samsung Series 9 .

MORE RESOURCES

- Blog post on this addressing it from a Windows Phone Requirement read

  - best bet - looks eerily like the info above - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2012/11/06/are-you-slat-compatible-wp8-sdk-tip-01.aspx
  - MUST READ Second Level Address Translation Benefits in Hyper-V R2 - http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/general/second-level-address-translation-benefits-hyper-v-r2.html
  - How to check if the Processor (CPU) supports the function SLAT?
    http://www.softwaretipspalace.com/how-to/260-check-slat-support-on-intel-amd-processors-cpu.html
  - SLAT Status Check Tool - http://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/
    CoreInfo download from SysInternals -
    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx

Post back with a status..  Healy in Tampa

Comment: SLATStatusCheck returned this:
 "Your machine does not have hardware virtualization capability. So, your machine is not SLAT capable."
so now what are my other options here? (if any)

Comment: Figure out how to get into your bios and see if there is an option to turn on 'hardware virtualization'.  What kind of machine is it?

Comment: Am I looking for the exact 'hardware virtualization' term? Because I have checked and only 'virtualization' is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: We can seach if you let us know what kind of machine you have?

Comment: Its a computer with average specs. For what I know about machine is that it has intel x64-based processor 2.10 GHz (Pentium) and 4gb RAM installed. 
Note: I really appreciate you getting back to my questions even though I am the one asking and replying late.

Answer (score 0):

Enter windows features in the Windows search box and select Turn Windows features on or off in the search results. In the Windows Features dialog, enable both Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform:

[image]

**After making these changes, reboot your computer.**

[see Hardware acceleration for emulator performance (Hyper-V & HAXM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows)